# How to change the gas price and gas limit in private blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, gas-price, gas-estimate

I wan to change the gas price and gas limit in the private blockchain as you know the currrent contract limit is 21000 so I want to change the default and also the gas limit I wan to cut more than 1 eth because there is the limit in the contract deployment fees.

All the work is for contract deplyment.

Comment: Which client are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For geth:

- `--gasprice`: Adjust the minimum gas price for transactions. The default is 1 Gwei, but you can change it as needed.
- `--targetgaslimit`: Set a target gas limit per block. The default is 4712388.

For Parity:

- `--min-gas-price`: Set the minimum gas price for transactions. Default is 0, meaning it accepts any gas price.
- `--gas-floor-target` and `--gas-cap`: Customize target and maximum gas limits per block. Default values are 4700000 and 6283184, respectively.

You can also define these parameters in your genesis file:

- `"gasLimit"`: Initial gas limit for the first block.
- `"minGasLimit"`: Minimum gas limit for your blockchain.

Comment: Parity has been deprecated for several years. It is better to not use it anymore.